# How can i get in touch with a miner

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, bitcoin-cash

Please can someone help me get in touch with a miner, i am trying to recover my bch sent to a segwit btc address.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bitcoin.SE is not a social networking site. You may want to search for 'bitcoin mining pools' and contact one that seems reputable to you.

Comment: If you want to ask in general how to go about solving your problem, you can ask a new question, but you'll need to include more details.

Comment: See https://bch.btc.com/docs/help/bch_segwit_recovery for example. I've no idea if they are trustworthy.